# Entities and relations in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm making a proof of concept, but I am no where near being good at crm dynamics.

I'm having the following situation

A company has multiple divisions, and each division can have accounts/clients. However an account/client can one or more divisions also a division can be active or innactive on a client.

Thus far I've tried using teams/acces teams then a subgrid to display teams associated with an account. But that gives a query error. Making me think due to an account/entity can only have on owner it is not the correct approach.

Then I've tried creating a new entity. "Division" with a field "Active:boolean" now I'm a bit worried that for every Account there will be a new record of division giving me numerous divisions whilst I only want the 5 divisons and a record for whether an account is bound to that division and if that division is active/inactive.

If someone could guide me in the right direction that would be very much appreciated!

EDIT/UPDATE:
So with the last comment I created a N:N relation between account and team (teams are conveniently created by the business units). Then on the form I added a subgrid, with Team and All Teams as view.

When I then load that grid it gives me this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.Xml.XmlException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #B7DC5153Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>System.Xml.XmlException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #B7DC5153</Message>
  <Timestamp>2016-05-25T13:53:32.9051677Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault>
    <ErrorCode>-2147217149</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>'Team' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'systemuserid'.</Message>
    <Timestamp>2016-05-25T13:53:32.9051677Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not that clear, but here are a few comments that hopefully should help.

1)  You should be able to add an N:N relationship between Teams and Accounts if that is your requirement.  And this would allow you to put that grid onto a form (posting the query error would help troubleshoot that particular issue).

2)  All CRM Records have Statuses and Status Reasons - you can use that for "Active" or "Inactive" on your Division entity, and CRM has some features that go with Activating/Deactivating records.

3)  It is usually pretty clear if you are creating a new record for each account vs using an existing record, my assumption is that you are using a lookup on the Account form to lookup the division you want.  When performing the lookup, you either choose an existing or create a new one.

4)  If you have different statuses on a single account for different divisions, then you would probably need some kind of linker record between the two entities, potentially use the OOB "Connections" for that, depending on your requirements.

5)  Teams in CRM are generally used for security/record access purposes, maybe that is why it seems a bit confusing as to how to leverage them in your scenario.  There are Ownership teams and Access teams, but both are related to who can get to which records.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm currently trying some things, I could use some more info on part 4 of your answer. I think that is what I need. I will again try creating an N:N relationship between teams and accounts and place a grid on accounts to get you that query error.

Comment: number 4 - Connections is an OOB way to link any record to any other record in CRM.  Go to the Entity properties within your solution under Communication and Collaboration and check Connections.  This should then show up in the left nav of whichever records you enable it on.  If you add a connection between the two (teams and accounts) and display a grid of connections, that should give you what you are looking for.  if you need more than just a connection and minimal metadata, then creating a new entity may be more appropriate.